# cypress test failes on timeout and and Mocha's done() called multiple times)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

i have a cypress test that keeps failing after a timeout even though all the tests pass.

I followed the migration guide: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide.html#Mocha-upgrade

But adding returns to the promises doesnt seem to fix the issue.

here is the code:

```
async function GetData() {
return await axios.get('/api/location').then((res) => {
    return res.data;
});
```

}

```
it.only('should prefill location details based on request', async function() {
    const locations = await GetData();
    locations.forEach((item, i) => {
        cy.get('[data-test="location-dropdown"]').click()
            cy.get(`div.ms-Callout button`).then((res) => {
                cy.get(res[i]).click();
                cy.get('[data-test="practice-name"]').should('have.attr', 'value', locations[i].name)
                cy.get('[data-test="address"]').should('have.attr', 'value', locations[i].address)
                cy.get('[data-test="contact-phone"]').should('have.attr', 'value', locations[i].phone.replace(/\s/g, ""))
                cy.get('[data-test="contact-url"]').should('have.attr', 'value', locations[i].url)
            })
        })
})
```

Kind of at my wits end with this issue so id appreciate a kindly pointer in the right direction

Comment: I fixed this by changing the axios request to a cypress one...weird!

Comment: Yes I would always recommend using cypress request rather than anything else when testing with cypress. Also your getData function just so you know you don’t need to return both I believe.